# component.get("v.colData.data") returning different result to component.get("v.colData").data

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I know I am doing something wrong. I'm just not sure what.
I have the following 2 ways of adding data to an attribute:

```
rowDataItems.push(rowDataItem = {
    name : colItems[j].name,
    data : rowData[colItems[j].name],
    type : colItems[j].type,
    class : colItems[j].class,
    indexed : colItems[j].indexed,
    subItems : colItems[j].subItems
});
```

And

```
rowDataItem.subItems.forEach(function(subItem) 
    subItem.data = rowDataItem.data[subItem.name];
});
```

My problem is that the first construct when referenced as component.get("v.colData") returns an Object with 'data' as a member.

```
{,...} in the Safari debugger
```

And both component.get("v.colData.data") and component.get("v.colData").data return the expected data structure.

The second construct when referenced as component.get("v.colData") returns an Object but it appears as

```
{data: {}} in the Safari debugger.
```

There is other data in the structure but that is how it displays in the debugger. component.get("v.colData.data") returns undefined whereas component.get("v.colData").data returns the expected data structure.

As I said I know I've done something wrong. I suspect it is how I've added the data in the structure. To use the data in my component I need component.get("v.colData.data") to work. Can anyone tell me why component.get("v.colData").data works but component.get("v.colData.data") doesn't and how I can get the request to return the expected data?

Thanks, Greg.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100% sure about it but my guess is that when using

```
component.get("v.colData.data")
```

aura is actually looking for an attribute that is called v.colData.data and as the attribute doesn't exist it brings back undefined

Comment: I fully agree. `component.get("v.colData.data")` and `component.get("v.colData").data` have two different meanings (here, `colData` has to be an Object or a Map).